# Image of the map induced on homology by a covering

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, covering

I asked this question on math.se (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647930/image-of-the-map-on-homology-induced-by-a-covering), but it have not attracted much of attention.

Let $X$ and $Y$ are two compact connected oriented 2dim smooth manifolds, and $\pi \colon X\to Y$ is an unramified covering of a finite degree. Consider the induced map $\pi_*\colon H_1(X,\mathbb Z)\to H_1(Y,\mathbb Z)$.

Question: is it true that the image of $\pi_*$ is a sublattice of $H_1(Y,\mathbb Z)$ of index $\#G$, where $G$ is the deck transformation group of $π$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is already false if $\pi $ is a Galois covering (i.e. $Y\cong X/G$): the index is the order of the *abelianized* group $G_{ab}$. Indeed from the exact sequence
$$\pi _1(X)\rightarrow \pi _1(Y)\rightarrow G\rightarrow 1$$we get an exact sequence
$$H_1(X,\Bbb{Z})\rightarrow H_1(Y,\Bbb{Z})\rightarrow G_{ab}\rightarrow 0\ .$$

Comment: For anyone else momentarily confused by the notation: the $\pi_1$ in this answer refers to the fundamental group whereas the $\pi_*$ in the question indicates the map induced on homology by the covering $\pi: X \to Y$.